# Bash versus Zsh: An Array Question with Example

Tags: arrays, bash, zsh

Here is an example of an array that works in Bash but not Zsh. Can someone explain why it fails and what the suitable syntax for Zsh would be to get the same results?

I know bash is index 0 and Zsh is index 1 but Im not understanding how this applies in this context.

```
#!/bin/bash
USER_LIST=$( ls /Users | grep -v -e 'Shared' -e 'Guest' )

for TARGET_USER in "${USER_LIST[@]}"; do
    TARGET_FILE="/Users/${TARGET_USER}/Library/Application Support/foo/example.txt"
    if [[ -e "$TARGET_FILE" ]]; then
        echo "The file '$TARGET_FILE' exists for user '$TARGET_USER'. It will be deleted now..."
        rm -f "$TARGET_FILE"
    else
         echo "The file '$TARGET_FILE' does NOT exist for user '$TARGET_USER'. No action required."
    fi
done
```

Comment: That's not actually an array; it's a multi-word string. An array needs an extra set of parentheses: `USER_LIST=($( ls /Users | grep -v -e 'Shared' -e 'Guest' ))`

Comment: Apparently bash ignores `[@]` when the variable is a string rather than an array, which is why it seems to work there.

Comment: Because Bash and Zsh are not compatible.

Comment: @JohnKugelman : While what you say is correct, but given the **concrete code** posted here, I still don't see at which point the differences between `bash` and `zsh` would show up. Of course indexing would be a candidate, in particular when the variable is not an array, but a scalar, as you correctly point out, but in this code, the only "indexing" happens in `for TARGET_USER in "${USER_LIST[@]}"`, and as I tried out, this would behave the same in bash and zsh. Also, the usage of the variables inside the loop does not seem to touch any language difference related to bash/zsh.

Comment: @Barmar: I did a `a="a b";  for f in "${a[@]}"; do echo $f; done` and it works the same in bash and zsh. In both cases, the loop is executed once and `f` is set to `'a b'. This might not be what the OP wants, but at least the behaviour is consistent between bash and zsh.

Comment: `[@]` isn't ignored; it just treats a non-array parameter the same as an array with exactly one value, just like `$USER_LIST` and `${USER_LIST[0]}` (or `${USER_LIST[1]}` in `zsh`) are the same.

Answer (score 3):

Use a glob to define the array.

```
# bash
shopt -s extglob
USER_LIST=( /Users/!(Shared|Guest) )
USER_LIST=( "${USER_LIST[@]#/Users/}" )

# zsh
setopt kshglob
USER_LIST=( /Users/!(Shared|Guest) )
USER_LIST=($USER_LIST:t)
```

Comment: This solution is clean, since you omit the invocation of `ls`, but it does not really answer the question, i.e. at which point the OP's code hits a difference between bash and zsh.

Comment: The OP claims a difference that I cannot reproduce.

Comment: Neither can I. I have voted to close it on the grounds that the problem is not reproducible. @DanielStranathan : You can amend your question by demonstrating the difference between bash and zsh you are talking about, and I would do a _reopen_.